# Difference between EOT lite und EOT compressed

Tags: webfonts, eot

What’s the difference between EOT lite and EOT compressed?

It says that EOT files have a domain binding built in, but for example I can convert my fonts to EOTs with the FontSquirrel converter where I cannot enter any URL where the files should be bound to.

Would be great if somebody could enlighten me! :)

Answer (score 9):

The domain binding isn't necessary and can be dropped. EOT Lite is effectively just a TTF with a different file ending while EOT compressed is just adding MTX compression to the mix. You can actually check that yourself by comparing a FontSquirrel generated TTF and EOT lite against each other in a hex editor. Except for a few additional flags the files are practically identical.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20160420072745/http://readableweb.com/jeffrey-zeldman-questions-the-eot-lite-web-font-format/)

Comment: So which one is preferable? Sounds like "EOT compressed", right?
caniuse doesn't distiguish between both...

Comment: I would ask the question differently... what are the use cases for eot light and eot compressed? "Best" is always depending on the situation and doesn't have a general answer.